# BottomNavigatorBar não está aceitando páginas. Como corrigir?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Eu estou tentando fazer um app que use o BottomNavigatorBar como ferramenta para navegar entre telas, porém, ao colocar uma página para ser executada após clicar em um dos ícones do menu, está retornando um erro de string.

[image: Aqui está o Erro]

Aqui está o código revelante para resolver o erro
O erro está em _widgetOptions, onde chamo uma das minhas telas criadas.

```
import 'package:app_work/telas/pendentes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text('Bom Dia'),
    PendentesPage(),
    Text('Boa noite')
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Página Inicial'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Pendentes'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Concluídas'),
          )
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex =  index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Código de PendentesPage()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PendentesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  PendentesPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _PendentesPageState createState() => _PendentesPageState();
}

class _PendentesPageState extends State<PendentesPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('TESTANDO'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual o código de `PendentesPage()` o erro pode está aí, não tem parâmetro no construtor?

Comment: Atualize com o código de PendentesPage()

Comment: Estranho este código compilar sem o parâmetro `title`, tente: `PendentesPage(title: 'Título da Página'),`

Comment: Resolvi o problema, para tal tive que mudar o tipo o extends para StatelessWidget

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é relacionado ao Widget "Text()", ele está ocorrendo porque você não inicializou o parâmetro "widget.title" que está sendo passado para sua classe "_MyHomePageState" através do construtor. Você está usando ele nesta classe sem antes inicializa-lo com um valor, e onde for utilizar 'MyHomePage()' ou 'PendentesPage()', os declare da seguinte forma: `NameClass(title: 'meu titulo')`. Creio que isso ira resolver

Comment: Este erro em questão informa que o parâmetro necessário no widget "Text()", que é uma String na sua declaração, está nulo, o que não é permitido, e se você não iniciar o valor de "widget.title", que está sendo utilizado em um dos "Text(widget.title)", ele sera chamado nulo quando utilizado, causando assim o erro em questão. espero que tenha entendido kkkkk